# Why is 'isInstance' not defined?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to build a little Python utility. I've built a unit test to test a basic setter, but my unit test fails with `NameError: name 'isInstance' is not defined`.

My code:

```
from pathlib import Path

class DirectoryStructureNormalizer:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self.__path

    @path.setter
    def path(self, path):
        self.__path = Path(path)
```

And my unit test:

```
import unittest

from pathlib import Path

from DirectoryStructureNormalizer import DirectoryStructureNormalizer


class DirectoryStructureNormalizerTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def testSetterShouldSetPathToPathlibPath(self):
        directoryStructureNormalizer = DirectoryStructureNormalizer('.')
        self.assertTrue(isInstance(directoryStructureNormalizer.path, Path))

def main():
        unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And finally, my output:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testSetterShouldSetPathToPathlibPath (__main__.DirectoryStructureNormalizerTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DirectoryStructureNormalizerTests.py", line 12, in testSetterShouldSetPathToPathlibPath
    self.assertTrue(isInstance(directoryStructureNormalizer.path, Path))
NameError: name 'isInstance' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I know I'm missing something super basic, but what?

Comment: You want `self.assertIsInstance` instead of `isInstance`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson That works! However, I'm still confuzzled as to why `isInstance` is not defined in that context? Is this expected? Why?

Comment: So the question is: why did you expect it to work? For Python to recognise a name, that name needs to be defined somewhere, usually either via an import or an assignment (though there are other mechanisms). The exception to that rule would be the builtins, but `isInstance` isn't a builtin. Possibly you wanted `isinstance`, which _is_ a builtin. but that's a different name:  Python identifiers are case-sensitive.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Right again! My fat fingers and java background camel-cased the `isInstance`, when I was really looking for the `isinstance` builtin. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `isinstance(..)` instead of `isInstance(..)`

The difference is the "i" is small letter - is***i***nstance(..)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two things:

- There is the built-in function [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) (written all-lowercase).
- And there is the [`assertIsInstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance) method of the `TestCase` class, which is roughly equivalent to `assertTrue(isinstance(...))`.